DPDK: Why speed_capa is not set for VF PCIs
Tried to get the port capabilities for the VF inside the container from DPDK.
Use rte_eth_dev_info_get which is mentioned in https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/features.html, but speed_capa inside rte_eth_dev_info is 0.
In DPDK NIC overview page: https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/overview.html, IAVF supports "Speed Capabilities", But in the code, https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk/blob/main/drivers/net/iavf/iavf_ethdev.c#L1135, speed_capa is not set in iavf_dev_info_get.
Does iavf really support "Speed Capabilities"? Is there any other way to get the speed capabilities?

Can you show your code when trying to use rte_eth_dev_info_get and getting bad speed_capa? Is iavf_dev_info_get an alternative method to rte_eth_dev_info_get get speed_capa ?
